# Query to find road paths of area

Tags: openstreetmap, query, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I am trying to find road information of [COLAC](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/3145220) region.My query is not working.

```
area[name="COLAC];
way(area)[highway=living_street]->.streets;
(
  way(around.streets:150);
  node(around.streets:150);
);
(._;>;);
out meta
```

Comment: Please explain what is not working for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spelling of the name "Colac" is not correct. You need to use exactly the same uppercase/lowercase as in the original OSM data.

Also, there's a missing semicolon towards the end of your query, which is a syntax error.

Then your area "Colac" doesn't have any highway=living_street in the OSM data, so you won't get any data in return.